# Android UI, picker to select a duration

Tags: android, user-interface, timepicker

In my app, I want my users to be able to select a duration (from 0 to 120 minutes).

I would like, if possible, to avoid using an `EditText` because it's not very user friendly.

I was thinking about using a TimePicker, with its nice wheels, but it seems that it's only possible to select minutes from 0 to 60.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could make the duration selection possible ?

Cheers.

Comment: You can use spinner (dropdown) as well, with autocomplete feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can use the [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) widget by default it will be provided by the android. In the `NumberPicker` you can set the Max and Min value according to your requirement ( 0 - 120).